# JOIN bills ON bills.item_id = cars.id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

There are two tables:

TABLE **bills**

```
item_id | price
c1 | 10000
m1 | 9000
m2 | 8000
```

TABLE **cars**

```
id | model
1 | toyota
2 | bmw
```

I need JOIN both tables, where item_id=id AND the first letter in item_id is 'c', so I need to get: **c1 | 10000 | 1 | toyota**

Comment: Why does `item_id` "c1" in `bills` link to `id` "1" in `cars`? Is it just because of the number 1? If that is the case, the 1 should be in its own column in `bills`, otherwise your joins are going to be slow.

Comment: What are the data types of your two columns? If one is int and the other is varchar, you would get a conversion error when trying to join on the ID fields.

Comment: Change your design to split the `item_id` field into at least two fields such as `item_type` *(car, motorboat, etc)* and `item_id`.  Concatenating multiple items of data into a single field is a SQL anti-pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * 
from cars c
join bills b on b.item_id = concat('c', c.id)
```

Note that performance is orders of magnitude better (and acceptable) joining in this order, because the calculation to generate the composite key is done once per *car*, rather than *once* per car/bill combination had I joined bills first then cars.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
select b.*, c.*
from bills b 
inner join cars c on convert(substring(b.item_id, 2, 8000), int) = c.id
where b.item_id like 'c%'
```